# NavigationSplitView works with .ID not with Object(struct)

Tags: swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationsplitview

In my project I want to navigate to the detail View in a NavigationSplitView. This however does not work, nothing happens. When I change the selection to the ID property all of it works. I made a very simple example view that demonstrates this (real project is bigger)

This doesn't work

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var notes = [
        Annotation(title: "Note 1", details: "Some details here", completed: false),
        Annotation(title: "Note 2", details: "Some details here too", completed: true),
        Annotation(title: "Note 3", details: "Some details here also", completed: false)
    ]
    
    @State private var selected: Annotation?
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: .constant(.doubleColumn)) {
            List (selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(notes) { annotation in
                        Text(annotation.title)
                    }
            }
        } detail: {
            VStack {
                Text(selected?.title ?? "-")
                Text(selected?.details ?? "-")
                //Text(selected?.uuidString ?? "###")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Annotation: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: String
    var details: String
    var completed: Bool
}
```

This works

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var notes = [
        Annotation(title: "Note 1", details: "Some details here", completed: false),
        Annotation(title: "Note 2", details: "Some details here too", completed: true),
        Annotation(title: "Note 3", details: "Some details here also", completed: false)
    ]
    
    @State private var selected: Annotation.ID?
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: .constant(.doubleColumn)) {
            List (selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(notes) { annotation in
                        Text(annotation.title)
                    }
            }
        } detail: {
            VStack {
                //Text(selected?.title ?? "-")
                //Text(selected?.details ?? "-")
                Text(selected?.uuidString ?? "###")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Annotation: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: String
    var details: String
    var completed: Bool
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `ForEach` puts a `tag` on each item with the item's `id`. So, the selection is updated with that `id`. If you want the `tag` to match the entire item, you have to use the `tag` modifier to explicitly do that:

```
List (selection: $selected) {
    ForEach(notes) { annotation in
        Text(annotation.title)
             .tag(annotation) // <-- Here
    }
}
```

Note that this is potentially dangerous, as if your model had a property that changed when you were on the detail view, it would no longer stay selected, since the equality would be broken. So, it's probably best/safest to stick with the `id`-based selection.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear! I'll stick with the id!